# How to select a Dev Spaces controller in Azure AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-dev-spaces

I'm setting up a testing environment and want to deploy our services to a k8s cluster using Dev Spaces.

Following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/quickstart-nodejs?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) i got stuck when trying to run the code. After running the cmd "azds up" i got the error "No Azure Dev Spaces controller is selected. Run 'az aks use-dev-spaces' to get started."

Unfortunatelly this doesn't solve this issue. There is a controller in the Resource group in Azure which also contain the AKS and in the AKS, Dev Spaces is activated.

Any suggestions to at least come closer to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i had to manually select the controller and the space using the CLI.

```
azds controller select -g <resourceGroup> -n <controllerName>
azds space select
```